# Get executing assembly version in classic ASP

Tags: .net

Is it possible to get the executing .NET assembly version in a classic ASP page?

Comment: How relates `asp` with `.net`? In general, If can get access to registry, you can retrieve that information from their.

Comment: I have doubts that you could, since classic ASP is a legacy framework.  When I had to mix the two, I had to set separate session variables, since those were handled quite differently.  I'd check the server variables in the request object to see if that information is available.

Comment: Will a classic ASP page execute inside a .NET assembly? You can't get its version because it doesn't exist (their requests are even served in different processes). If you need to pass that information from one ASP.NET page to an ASP page then AFAIK you need to use a cookie or a parameter in your URL.

Comment: Classic ASP doesn't use the .net framework. As an analogy, you may have PHP installed on your copy of IIS, but you wouldn't expect a Classic ASP page to tell you which version of PHP.

Comment: Just to echo the comments of others, there is no "executing .NET assembly" when a Classic ASP page is being rendered so the question doesn't really even make sense.

Comment: we are using both the classic asp and aspx page in same project. For aspx page we have got it through the reflection. Like that, is there is any method to get the version in classic asp, same as reflection in .net

Comment: Thanks for every one i got the .net executing assembly version in classic asp page.